# Movie scene where woman is comforting father of dead son by saying he is alive somehow

Tags: story-identification, movie

A father, whose son is dead, and a woman are sitting on a porch, looking at the stars. The father is crying and the woman is talking about his son like he is still alive. She says things like:

- This is your son 2 years old, walking around.
- This is your son 10 years old, playing football, he is so strong.
- This is your son 15 year with his first girlfriend, she is beautiful.

I only remember this very specific scene, the movie was probably sf. But actually I don't remember the rest of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description is incredibly similar to a scene in the 2002 film [Minority Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_Report_(film)), starring Tom Cruise.

The scene in question is viewable at: